# continue with same Show and hide divs when we change page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, show-hide

I work with a function in my main page. All works fine, I just want to know how to use the function :

```
localStorage.setItem("language", selectedLanguage);

currentlanguage= localStorage.getItem("language");
```

My goal is to keep the select language in a page when i click on a link and go in another page.

For example id="en" is the language by default, but if I want to use id="fr" in my main page, and click on link who will send me in another page. I will come back to id="en". So how can I use localStorage to keep the same language ?

Here is the jsfiddle of the function that I use:

```
https://jsfiddle.net/kodjoe/chvw181j/
```

HERE IS MY HTML CODE

```
<a class="button" id="en">EN</a>
<a class="button" id="fr">FR</a>
<a class="button" id="de">DE</a>


<div class="lan en">1</div>
<div class="lan fr">2</div>
<div class="lan de">3</div>
<div class="lan en">4</div>
<div class="lan fr">5</div>
<div class="lan de">6</div>
```

HERE IS MY JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.lan').hide();
$('.en').show();
});

$('.button').click(function(event) {
$('.lan').hide();
var selectedLanguage = $(this).attr('id');
var setActiveLanguage = "." + selectedLanguage;
$(setActiveLanguage).show();

localStorage.setItem("language", selectedLanguage);
currentlanguage= localStorage.getItem("language");
});
```

HERE IS MY CSS

```
.button { cursor:pointer; padding: 0px 30px; }
```

Comment: you will need to store the active language, maybe with `localStorage`

Comment: You can but I guess you will need some sort of localstorage or session

Comment: As @depperm suggested: localStorage or maybe even cookies ... Keeping language within the link is also an option but I would never recommend it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
localStorage.setItem("language", selectedLanguage);

currentlanguage= localStorage.getItem("language");
```

Comment: you can use the `localStorage.getItem('language')` on any of your pages to get the current language

Comment: in this example language isn't used in my code, i need to add it somewhere ?

Comment: it can be any name you want,   once set that localStorage variable  is available in any page

Comment: So If I understand it well, I need to put this part of code in all my pages in javascript section, like i did ? I updated my question and add the function at the end of my js part

Comment: its like cookies,   once you set the variable localStorage.setItem("language", selectedLanguage);      the value can be accesed in any page,        using localStorage.getItem("language").                                                                        no need to put in all pages

Comment: Ok thank you @SteveFox so my part of code is okay for my main page, for others pages I will just need to duplicate the jspart without the localstorage part ? thank you

Answer (score 0):

You could use [SessionStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage) to save your data (like selected language). Then expend your functions with if-clauses to set the right show/hide-status.

Answer (score 0):

You could use localStorage, but I would just put the code in a file where you'd like to include any global scripts, since you will or already do have other scripts that are applicable to the application as a whole. Then link the file in your head (you'd likely be using an include of some sort for your header content).

`<script src="js/globalScripts.js"></script>`

```
//globalScripts.js

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.lan').hide();
    $('.en').show();
});

$('.button').click(function(event) {
    $('.lan').hide();
    var selectedLanguage = $(this).attr('id');
    var setActiveLanguage = "." + selectedLanguage;
    $(setActiveLanguage).show();
});
```